# Issue with replacments on kubernetes. Not possible to build kustomize with replacing secret

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

replacements:

- source:
  namespace: argocd
  kind: Secret
  name: repository-ssh-argocd
  fieldPath: data.url.value
  targets:

  - select:
    kind: Application
    name: NAME-OF-APPLICATION
    fieldPaths:

    - spec.source.repoURL

I am creating secret on cluster with external secret which is taken out of Secret manager, so secret is already created in the namespace: argocd

Secret exist on the cluster in the namespace argocd. But its not created on the level of kustomization.yaml which i'm trying to build

Error: nothing selected by Secret.[noVer].[noGrp]/repository-ssh-argocd.argocd:data.url.value

Not sure why its not able to build it this way, is it possible to do work arround?

```
kubectl get secret -n argocd repository-ssh-argocd -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  enableLfs: ENABLE_FS_IS_HERE
  insecure: INSECURE_IS_HERE
  sshPrivateKey: SSH KEY WAS HERE
  url: THERE WAS AN URL HERE
immutable: false
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    reconcile.external-secrets.io/data-hash: XXXXXXXX
  creationTimestamp: "XXXXX"
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: repository
    reconcile.external-secrets.io/created-by: fXXXX
  name: repository-ssh-argocd
  namespace: argocd
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ExternalSecret
    name: external-secret-ssh-argocd
    uid: 4XXXX
  resourceVersion: "1XXX"
  uid: XXXX
type: Opaque
```

PLEASE HELP!

to create a replacment in the manifest of the application of argo, i've tried few different path and even var which is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

Your k8s secret doesn't have `url` key inside

Comment: updated with output of my secret, url was there just was deleted by accident